# ASP MVC 2 in Sharepoint 2007 Security Exception

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, sharepoint-2007, web-config

I am trying to configure ASP MVC 2 Framework to run within a SharePoint 2007 install on IIS 6.0. I have managed to get the two web.config setups together, and made GAC and global.asax changes.

When I try to access the MVC application within the SharePoint domain (http://Sharepoint.com/MVCApp), I get a security exception.

```
**Source Error:** 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.  

**Stack Trace:** 

[SecurityException: Request for the permission of type 'System.Web.AspNetHostingPermission, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.]
   System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerWrapper.System.Web.Mvc.IBuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies() +14
   System.Web.Mvc.TypeCacheUtil.FilterTypesInAssemblies(IBuildManager buildManager, Predicate`1 predicate) +88
   System.Web.Mvc.TypeCacheUtil.GetFilteredTypesFromAssemblies(String cacheName, Predicate`1 predicate, IBuildManager buildManager) +65
   System.Web.Mvc.AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas(RouteCollection routes, IBuildManager buildManager, Object state) +80
   System.Web.Mvc.AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas(Object state) +55
   System.Web.Mvc.AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas() +7
   CapExRequest.MvcApplication.Application_Start() in C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\CapExRequest\CapExRequest\Global.asax.cs:29

 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.3603; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.3614
```

I have tried adding permissions to the MachineName\ASPNET account for the \MVCApplication as suggested in one article.  No joy.

Other occurences seem to be related to accessing a remote file share.  There is no remote file share in my instance.

Any thoughts, suggestions, answers??

Comment: Looking in the Global.asax.cs, it seems I overlooked the note about changes needed to enable MVC Routing in IIS 6.0: http://go.microsoft.com/?LinkId=9394801  Trying it out now...

Comment: Yeah, that didn't help.  The IIS 6.0 changes mentioned were already in place. The Global.asax changes must now be part of MVC 2.0. All the solutions I see online seem to expect IIS 7.0, using CASPOL, and/or unblocking the DLL. Can't figure out how these apply to my situation.

Comment: Okay, that was somewhat stupid.  Why does it have to take so long to recognize it though.  As it turns out, I had forgotten to move the MVC application (a signed application) into the GAC. Now to integrate SharePoint authentication...

Answer (score 0):

***So, here is what the setup is, and the steps taken to get it all together...***

- Followed basic instructions for
  running an ASP.NET MVC application in SharePoint (see link below), but I put the
  custom MVCHttpApplication in it's own
  project and created a standalone
  assembly;
- Updated SharePoint to include AJAX
  3.5 (ours was only referencing 1.0 standalone);
- Built a signed application and
  deployed to the virtual directory,
  including adding the application
  assembly in the GAC.

Actually pretty straight-forward so far. It just took a while to come to my senses.

"Using ASP>NET with Sharepoint Publishing" http://vspug.com/mbailey/files/2010/04/Using-ASP.NET-MVC-2-with-Sharepoint-Publishing.pdf